# Backbone click event not firing on dynamic view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view that creates a new div for each model that is passed into it.  However, I cannot get any sort of events to fire (click a.change-status) on the view and I assume it's because the elements inside of it are also generated from a template.  Please let me know if there's some way around this.

```
var videoDivView  = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '<div class="vendor-video" />',
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this);
    this.render();
    this.model.on('change:published', this.enableSaveButton);
},
events: {
    'click a.change-status'     : 'changeVideoStatus'
},
template: video_tmpl,
render: function(){
    this.$el.attr("id", 'video-'+this.model.id);
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.$el.data('status', video_statuses[this.model.get('published')]);
},
changeVideoStatus: function(e) {
    console.log(this.model);
    return false;   
}, 
enableSaveButton: function() {
    $('#save-changes').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

an example template would look like:

```
<script id="single-video-tmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div>
    <div class="video-info">
        <span class="video-title"><%=video_title%></span>
        <div class="bottom-info">
            <a href="#<%=id%>" class="change-status"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</script>
```

Comment: the `el` attribute you're setting doesn't make sense, it should be a jquery like selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I'm having it create a div for each model

Comment: Oh, does that work? I've never seen it used like that to be honest, sorry.

Comment: That's okay.  Yes, it works great that way depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think it might be because the element is only created after it has initialized. So at initialization (where the `events` object is parsed) it can't bind the click events to any element in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed.  I imagine there has to be a way around it, the answer below seems that would be the solution but it's not working

Comment: where are you putting the `this.delegateEvents()` exactly?

Comment: I tried putting it in the render function after the html was added

Comment: Do you have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with this?

Comment: Is your `a` element actually empty when you render it? Try: `<a href="#<%=id%>" class="change-status">Some Text Here</a>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some things that might be the cause of the problem.

First of all, your `el` declaration seems to be suspect. If you want a div with that class you just have to define the `className` attribute since the default for backbone views is `div`.

Instead of: `el: '<div class="vendor-video" />'`

just use: `className: 'vendor-video'`

I don't see any details about your view initialization methods but the best practice is to initialize a view and then render it to the container:

```
var yourVideoDivView = new videoDivView({model: model});
$("#your-video-container").html(yourVideoDivView.render().el)
```

also to get the last line work you have to `return this;` on your render method.

```
render: function(){
  ...
  return this;
}
```

About using `this.delegateEvents()`, you should call this function after your view is already in the `DOM` otherwise it makes no sense. ie:

```
$("#your-video-container").html(yourVideoDivView.render().el)
yourVideoDivView.delegateEvents();
```

`delegateEvents()` will makes your view events alive again.

Comment: so if I run div.$el.find('a.change-status').trigger('click'); right after delegateEvents() it fires, but otherwise if I click it will not fire.  Do you think it could have to do with that this is wrapped inside a couple other views?  It's wrapped in a videoSet view that's then wrapped in a larger view.  Would that effect this?

Comment: nevermind, I had to render the parent view the same way as above, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Try a `this.delegateEvents()` after you render the new content.

Comment: I tried adding that in and it didn't seem to change anything :(

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
You can resolve this problem in two steps. 
- Create a `tagName` in view
- Append your template in `this.$el`
That's all. 
And it work without `this.delegateEvents()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue I observed with tagName and appending using this.$el is, the event listener failed to attach the event for the last element created with selected tagName. But, the problem got solved when using this.delegateEvents() after appending the elements to DOM.